# E: Failed to fetch ... 404 Not Found \n E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, updates, ffmpeg

I am receiving

```
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libavdevice57 libsdl2-2.0-0
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg libavdevice57 libsdl2-2.0-0
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 574 not upgraded.
Need to get 378 kB/2.040 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3.824 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0 amd64 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.1.... 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsdl2/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 10.1.... 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

If I browse http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsdl2/
as the message says, there is no

`libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1_amd64.deb`.

There are, for instance, files

`libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.3_amd64.deb`

`libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

Actually, I do not see *any* file `*18.04.1*`. I see some `*18.04.3*`, `*16.04.01*` files, and others with no specific version.

So, **Can I perform the intended `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` without `upgrade`ing?**:

1. Can that file be located somewhere else? (and how to tell Ubuntu to use it).

   I googled [like this](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&ei=8eTYXIaVLJ-e5OUPu4i6aA&q=libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8%2Bdfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1_amd64.deb).
   The first link does not have the file, either in the page displayed or in the source.
   From the second link, I managed to get [`libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1_amd64.deb`](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/371655237/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1_amd64.deb).
2. Can that file be superseded by some other alternative? (and how to tell Ubuntu to do so... see `... upgrade` below)

What I tried:

1. `$ sudo apt-get update`

   `$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`
2. `$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg --fix-missing`
3. `$ sudo apt-get clean`

   `$ sudo apt-get update`

   `$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`
4. Replacing in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
   all the instances of `us.archive`, `archive` or `security` by `old-releases`, in lines `http://<search string>.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ ...`
   (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30843486/2707864).
   I got errors like

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   Err:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release
     404  Not Found [IP: 10.1.... 80]
   Err:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release
     404  Not Found [IP: 10.1.... 80]
   Err:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports Release
     404  Not Found [IP: 10.1.... 80]
   Err:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release
     404  Not Found [IP: 10.1.... 80]
   Reading package lists... Done
   E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
   E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
   ...
   ```

What I did not try:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I am not sure if I risk my system having issues which may take time to fix. If so, I would upgrade when I have some time available to deal with the potential contingency.

Comment: Look like you have tried a couple different things, none of which worked...but you didn't clean up your mess before trying the next blind alley. Don't use old-releases.ubuntu.com (18.04 won't be there for many years). Disable what appears to be a proxy that you set up (IP: 10.*.*.* is not a valid internet address).

Comment: @user535733 - I tried item 4 just for completeness and I reported the results (which I expected).
I am behind a corporate firewall, but that doesn't seem to be the problem here... or is it?

Comment: Based upon the IP address, your corporate firewall looks like *exactly* the problem. Contact your IT department to find out their preferred solution.

Comment: Please add output of `grep -ir proxy /etc/apt` and ``apt-cache policy squid-deb-proxy-client`` to the question.